# windows application c#.net setup not working with out visual studio in other system

Tags: c#, .net

Hi guys  my windows application c#.net setup not working with out visual studio installed in other system.though i av installed sql server database and dotnet framework.,showing sql exception .,can any one give solution

Comment: are you trying to run .exe file?

Comment: yes dude am trying to run my exe file in other system .,actually i av used mdf file in my application .,

Comment: hey which exception you are getting?

Comment: how to post my error snapshot here?., showing sql exception .,

Comment: Any one faced this kind of issues?

Comment: @rahul, we are still waiting for an exception. You can post it as a text

Comment: hi guys any one can help me to solve this?